# Fast Image Loading from Network Drive in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a C# application that needs to load about 50 TIFF images from a network drive. Each of these images has a size of about 10-15 MByte. I have to load these images, resize them, and export them in a PDF file.

Currently, I am using the following method to load the images from the network drive

```
Image image = Bitmap.FromFile(path.LocalPath);
```

The problem is that loading the 50 images takes quite a lot time that is not tolerable for my application scenario. Is there a way to speed up the image loading process?

Comment: How long does it take to copy the files to your local drive and then copy the PDFs back again? I'm guessing it will be pretty close to the 15 minute mark :) If not, try copying the file before doing `Bitmap.FromFile`, and loading from the local drive instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you copy them to a local drive first. I suspect that `Bitmap.FromFile` may seek around the file (possibly reading redundantly) in a way which isn't a good fit for network drives - whereas just copying the files locally and then using `Bitmap.FromFile` does the expensive part (the network transfer) once.

Comment: Unbelievable. Using your suggestion I was able to reduce the time from about 20 minutes to 2 minutes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can also double the speed again by using a `StreamReader` and loading in the bitmap with `FromStream(stream,false,false)`. But this jump lots of checks that `FromFile()` is doing. I you know the file will always be correct go for it.

Comment: @Franck: Do you mean `MemoryStream` / `FileStream`? `StreamReader` is for text...

Comment: Right my bad, didn't check my projects before commenting. I looked and in my case i use `MemoryStream` . I did not try `FileStream` as i have the feeling it has a bit more checks than `MemoryStream` so it could be slower but i can't confirm that it's simply a hunch.

Comment: @Franck: `FileStream` and `MemoryStream` are just different streams - neither of them are going to check anything about the image. But yes, if you've got the image data entirely in memory then that probably would be faster than going to disk...

Comment: @JonSkeet i have compared speeds both ways and `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\test.jpg")), false, false)` vs `Image.FromFile("c:\\test.jpg")`  on a 1,141 Mb file i get between 1ms and 3ms on `FromStream` vs 30ms to 46ms on the `FromFile`. So his 2 minutes now can possibly be cutted down again by 10 to 40 times i guess.

Comment: @Franck: I wouldn't bet on it. There could be all kinds of different things at play here, including data caching messing up your benchmarks. Loading 500MB of images in a couple of minutes sounds reasonable to me...

Comment: i load 821 meg of images at once in 458 ms in my current project using `FromStream`. it's 611 files. Switching to `FromFile` takes 18,909 ms and sometime i get out of memory exceptions. Rebooting to retry and make sure nothings in memory the `FromFile` take 22,695 ms first time then around the 18-19 thousands for the next 2 times. I wonder how it can be properly tested because i only load them in a list generic.

Comment: @Franck: So that's already a very different situation to the OP's - lots of small files, rather than 50 large TIFFs. If the OP is unhappy with the performance, they can come back and have a look at your comments - but I think it's probably okay...